# Noise-blocking earplugs

Tags: audio, earphones

I realise this may not be the correct SE Site for the question, so if anyone could point me towards the correct one that would be helpful, but this seemed appropriate!

I'm looking for a pair of noise blocking earphones. I work in a loud office environment, and really struggle to focus with any sort of noise. I'm not looking for suggestions on how to get around this in any other way however - I'm working on that!

I was hoping to get a pair of earplugs/earphones/headphones that will block out as much sound as possible. Due to the environment, I suspect noise-cancelling won't be an awful lot of use however. I would be hoping to pay under £100, but suggestions at different pricing points would be helpful if anyone has any recommendations that they can personally vouch for.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not a computer hardware recommendation. Unfortunately, I don't know of another StackExchange that's designed really for this type of question; maybe https://workplace.stackexchange.com?

Comment: I would recommend going to https://www.reddit.com/r/headphones/

Comment: @JMY1000 What is wrong with this question? Speakers, headphones and earbuds are on-topic here, as long as they have enough requirements.

Comment: @Noah Are you going to be listening to music/podcasts/audio-books/other audio while wearing these? I know you are open to any type, but do you prefer earbuds over headphones or vise versa? Is there anything else you can add to the question to help us narrow down a product for you?

Comment: @Cfinley Because of the specific mention of earplugs and the fact that it's for noise isolation exclusively, not in conjunction with normal listening. Unfortunately that's not really hardware. A question about noice isolating/cancelling headphones/earbuds would be more on topic.

Comment: Hi all - they were just for noise cancelling. We've since gone with the Bose!

Answer (score 2):

When it comes to quiet earplugs then Sony’s noise-cancelling model [Sony WF-1000X](https://www.whathifi.com/sony/wf-1000x/review) is a great choise at around £90 on sale in Sweden right now.

A budget alternative would be the [Optoma NuForce BE2](https://www.digitaltrends.com/headphone-reviews/optoma-nuforce-be2-review/) which you can find for about £35 in online stores.